# Why is my output null every time?

Tags: java, swing

Hello I have a class that opens a JFrame and takes in a text. But when I try getting the text it says its null. 
Everytime I click the button I want the System.out to print the text I entered in the textArea.

This is my first class :

```
public class FileReader {

    FileBrowser x = new FileBrowser();
    private String filePath = x.filePath;

    public String getFilePath(){

        return this.filePath;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader x = new FileReader();
        if(x.getFilePath() == null){
            System.out.println("String is null.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(x.getFilePath());
        }
    }
}
```

This is a JFrame that takes in the input and stores it in a static String.

```
/*
 * This class is used to read the location 
 * of the file that the user.
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class FileBrowser extends JFrame{

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JButton button;
    public static String filePath;

    public FileBrowser(){
        super("Enter file path to add");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.textArea = new JTextArea();
        this.button = new JButton("Add file");

        add(this.textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(this.button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 100);
        setVisible(true);

        this.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                filePath = new String(textArea.getText());
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

But everytime I run these programs I get

```
String is null.
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect it to be and why?

Comment: I want it to be "Test" or anything I type in the textArea. I want to use the text entered.

Comment: That is the question I had :/ Why is it not printing out Test? :/

Comment: Why do you expect it to print Test and why?

Comment: Basically the overall use of this method is : 
The user will run this program, a GUI will pop up asking for the file path. I want to use the file path entered in the text area and check if the file exists. So far I was able to get the GUI to pop up and exit on clicking Add file. Next I want to get the text entered and store it in a different variable.

Comment: You're telling us what you want to do and why you want to do it, but you're not explaining how what you've done accomplishes that.

Comment: Basically I am asking you how I should go about with what I have so far :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken by the way how JFrames work. A JFrame does not stall the execution of the code until it is closed. So, basically, your code creates a JFrame and then grabs the `filePath` variable in that object, before the user could have possibly specified a file.

So, to solve this, move the code that outputs the filepath to stdout to the `ActionListener` you have. Get rid of the `System.exit()` call, and use `dispose()` instead.

---

**Update**: You should have this code for the ActionListener:

```
this.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        filePath = new String(textArea.getText());

        if(filePath == null){
            System.out.println("String is null.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(filePath);
        }

        dispose();
    }
});
```

And as main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    FileBrowser x = new FileBrowser();
}
```

Comment: I added my main into the ActionListener. but I am still getting the output as null.

Also how do I use the `dispose()` ?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had one more quick question. How do I use the text entered in the text area in another class? :/

Comment: Create a class with a constructor that takes the String and stores that string into his own member variables. Then call a method on that object, for example.

Comment: So basically, I am doing most of my coding in the `ActionListener` here?

Comment: Yes, you launch it from the action listener. You want to start doing things after the user has specified a file, so yes, in the action listener should most things go.

Comment: I added `dispose()` now the frame wont close when I click the button.

Comment: That is maybe because your code doesn't reach `dispose()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your main does not wait until the user has specified a text in the textArea. You could prevent this behaviour by looping until the text in the textArea is set or you could place the logic of the main function into the ActionListener to handle the event.
Following the second way the main function only creates a new FileBrowser object.